# Function Parameters VS Private Reference

Tags: .net

I have tried searching here via https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=parameters+vs+private+reference

My coding started out something similar to this(I have removed a lot of the other code from validation to try..catches just to keep the viewed code simple), where I pass the data table to the function:

```
Private Function get_value_from_datatable(dt As DataTable, condition As String, column_value_to_return As String) As String
    Dim return_value As String = ""
    If dt IsNot Nothing Then
        Dim drs() As DataRow
        drs = dt.Select(condition)
        If drs.Count = 1 Then
            return_value = drs(0)(column_value_to_return)
        End If
    End If
    get_value_from_datatable = return_value
End Function
```

After some reading, I found myself wondering if this is better/faster/preferred, as I presently have one data table only:

```
Private priv_datatable As DataTable ' Which gets set somewhere in the code before the ff function is called.'
Private Function get_value_from_datatable(condition As String, column_value_to_return As String) As String
    Dim return_value As String = ""
    If priv_datatable IsNot Nothing Then
        Dim drs() As DataRow
        drs = priv_datatable.Select(condition)
        If drs.Count = 1 Then
            return_value = drs(0)(column_value_to_return)
        End If
    End If
    get_value_from_datatable = return_value
End Function
```

It's just that I want to do the best practice and understand why one might be preferred over the other. It also came to mind that maybe, in the future, I will have more than one data table to access, but I do not know if that will happen soon or many months later.

Comment: Inside private methods you can do anything you feel is right.

Answer (score 0):

A deep question with ramifications most programmers are unaware of. My architecture prohibits parameters.

Parameters represent "immediate control" by the consumer. In other words, the consumer must manually control the function (with parameters) to operate it. Immediate control is a favorite of micromanagers, because they don't care to be organized.

Properties a function depend on represent "continuous control". The consumer can configure the function **before** firing it at any time chosen. Execution does not require manually delivering the data all at once. When you've done this a few times, you will not go back to parameters.

A collaborative (manufacturing) process goes even further by modeling control variables as what I call "reference properties."

```
   public Cvar<int> X { get; set; }
```

Modules in a process can be bound to the same variables and thereby change any other module's configuration in-process, which is obviously superior to the immediate control of assigning literal values by passing parameters. A process therefore consists of modules which interact with data points not each other. These modules contain only one function -- M() below, and the rest of the structure houses inputs and outputs.

```
    class Machine1Product
    {
        public Cvar<int> Y { get; set; }
    }
    class Machine1 : Producer<Machine1Product>, IMachine
    {
        public Cvar<int> X { get; set; }
        public void M()
        {
            // work which changes only product data points
        }
    }
```

The process itself only houses the modules and does nothing other than allocate memory (in D() below) and bind (in O() below) data points. This documents the process's data supply chain.

```
    // the process's DTO or finished product
    class MyProduct
    {
        public Cvar<int> X { get; set; }  // a reference to an int variable
        public Cvar<int> Y { get; set; }
        public Cvar<int> Z { get; set; }
    }
    class Process1 : Producer<MyProduct>, IProcess, IMachine
    {
        public Machine1 One { get; set; }
        public Machine2 Two { get; set; }

        // instantiates all machines and product properties 
        public void D() { ... }

        // binds each machine to interact with the product of this process
        public void O()
        {
            One.X = Product.X;            // the machine consumes X
            One.Product.Y = Product.Y;    // the machine changes Y

            Two.Y = Product.Y;            // the machine consumes Y
            Two.Product.Z = Product.Z;    // the machine changes Z
        }

        // observable, controllable and communication-free execution
        public void M()
        {
            One.M();
            Two.M();
        }
    }
```

**Integration and binding**

http://www.powersemantics.com/o.html

Technically, parameters mean data is copied to the called function's stack frame which is performance-friendly if the data was originally on the stack. However, if the data was originally on the heap, the caller must fetch it and incur cache misses. In short, there's no difference for the called method to fetch it from the heap itself. I can't say whether subsequent fetches by different modules in the same process cause additional cache misses though.

Object fields and properties live on the heap. Only in-function local value-type data values are on the stack. That's another big thing to explain. https://jonskeet.uk/csharp/memory.html

Finally, be aware a consumer shouldn't **extract** data from what's passed in, like in your example code. That's a reason for a separate "Extractor" module. Separate producers from consumers to free function bodies from site specificity.

Extract until you achieve **control**.

Comment: Thank you. I have read this twice and am still trying to understand it. I hope I can make a follow-up here if I have a question.